# OpenCV -SolvePNP how to compute guess from world coords

Tags: c++, opencv, math, rotation, algebra

For cv::SolvePNP, I would like to provide an initial guess for translation and rotation.
For the guess, I have the translation in world space and the rotation as up and direction vector (or Euler angles).
How do we transform the world space translation and up/direction vector to the correct format so cv:: SolvePNP can use it as as proper guess in the correct coordinate system?

I use useExtrinsicGuess=true, and provide tvec and rvec.

I computed a rotation matrix from the up and direction vectors, though there seems to be different conventions.
And then convert the rotation matrix with Rodrigues to rvec.
We use 
Tvec=-R*worldspace_tvec.
However, the results are clearly not right as the guess places the resulting tvec and rvec in a different place once converting it back to Euler/world space translation.
Is there a fast way to go from up/direction vectors and world space translations to the correct tvec and rvec inputs for SolvePNP?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have a look at opengl documentation or a computer graphics lecture (model-view teansformation). You'll probably. need the camera extrinsics in global coordinates and inverse-transform the global object coordinates with them.

Comment: The object points are also in the same global coordinates. Just tvec and rvec are not expected to be global by SolvePnP. SolvePnP expects Rodrigues rotation but it’s not defined in the documentation of what type of rotation matrix is expected before converting to Rodrigues. Eg OpenGL vs OpenCV vs eigen all use different conventions. The object space translation that SolvePnP expects depends on that rotation as well to transform from world space to whatever SolvePnP expects.

Comment: you can reverse engineer if you compute an artificial sample without guess and use the result as a guess to repeat (assumed result: same result). The used camera coordinate system of opencv is: x=right; y=down; z=viewingDirection

Comment: Like this? It's not yielding the correct results.
Eigen::Vector3d xaxis = up.cross(direction);
xaxis.normalize();
Eigen::Matrix3d rotationMatrix2;
rotationMatrix2.col(0) = xaxis;
rotationMatrix2.col(1) = -up; // OPENCV down vector
rotationMatrix2.col(2) = direction; 
cv::Mat R_input2;
cv::eigen2cv(rotationMatrix2, R_input2);
R_input2_org = R_input2.t();
cv::Rodrigues(R_input2_org, r_vec);
t_vec = -R_input2_org*translationVector;